# Do iOS content blockers work in Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome

Do the content blockers that can be installed with iOS 9 work in Chrome for iOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Content blockers are part of the Mobile Safari framework, so any third party app that uses Apple's SDK will inherit those extensions.

The current Chrome app (version 45.0.2454.89) doesn't appear to take advantage of Apple's offering. You might wait a long time for Google to cut into emir revenue stream by blocking trackers and advertising, but stranger things have happened.